# Dash is ignoring url_base_pathname for requests

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to get Dash to add a prefix to the URLs it fetches data from, so instead of loading a resource like /dash-layout it requests /my/prefix/dash-layout.

I understand that there is a parameter url_base_pathname (https://dash.plotly.com/reference) that does just that. There are two more parameters, requests_pathname_prefix and routes_pathname_prefix that have a similar function but its value default to url_base_pathname.

Setting requests_pathname_prefix can be done, either by passing requests_pathname_prefix="/my/prefix/" on the Dash constructor or using the DASH_URL_BASE_PATHNAME environment variable. Either method appears to be recognized as Dash prints:

Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/my/custom/path/

However, I see that while loading up http://127.0.0.1:8050/my/custom/path/ does indeed work, Dash is still requesting without the prefix, ie calling /dash-layout (among other resources). I examined the source code with the Developer Tools and came to find that the prefix appears to not be set as it seems to be null.

[image: dash-layout being requested without prefix]
[image: url_base_pathname is null]

This is despite the program printing:

```
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/my/custom/path/

 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: on
```

Comment: What is your Dash version ? Can you add the code snippet where you specify `url_base_pathname` ?